# Get data from Array in JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to get the `timestamp` of the object where `new_name` in `status_change` is **Solved**.

I have tried this.

```
console.log(
 ticket.updates ? 
 (
  (ticket.updates.find(x => x.status_change !== null) && 
   ticket.updates.find(x => x.status_change !== null).status_change.new_name === 'Solved') ?
  ticket.updates.find(x => x.status_change !== null).timestamp : 
   'new_name is ' + ticket.updates.find(x => x.status_change !== null).status_change.new_name
 ) 
 : 'No updates');
```

But above code didn't give the expected result.

Here is my data set.

```
{
    "updates": [{
            "timestamp": "2018-04-26 06:39:12",
            "by": {
                "name": "A1"
            },
            "status_change": {
                "new_name": "Open",
                "old_name": null
            }
        }, {
            "timestamp": "2018-04-27 00:09:44",
            "by": {
                "name": "B1"
            },
            "status_change": null
        }, {
            "timestamp": "2018-04-27 00:10:09",
            "by": {
                "name": "B1"
            },
            "status_change": {
                "new_name": "Solved",
                "old_name": "Open"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What could be the issue? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/608t7rL1/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use more than one boolean in `find()` to short-circuit it so you don't need the repeated `find()` calls:

```js
let obj = {"updates": [{"timestamp": "2018-04-26 06:39:12","by": {"name": "A1"},"status_change": {"new_name": "Open","old_name": null}}, {"timestamp": "2018-04-27 00:09:44","by": {"name": "B1"},"status_change": null}, {"timestamp": "2018-04-27 00:10:09","by": {"name": "B1"},"status_change": {"new_name": "Solved","old_name": "Open"}}]}

let item = obj.updates.find(item => 
   item.status_change
   && item.status_change.new_name == "Solved")

if (item) { // found one
  console.log(item.timestamp)
} else {   // not found
  console.log("no new items")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and help me to reduce the repeated `find()` calls

Answer (score 1):

You can first use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the not required objects. And then use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the necessary fields.

Here is how:

```js
const data = {
    "updates": [{
            "timestamp": "2018-04-26 06:39:12",
            "by": {
                "name": "A1"
            },
            "status_change": {
                "new_name": "Open",
                "old_name": null
            }
        }, {
            "timestamp": "2018-04-27 00:09:44",
            "by": {
                "name": "B1"
            },
            "status_change": null
        }, {
            "timestamp": "2018-04-27 00:10:09",
            "by": {
                "name": "B1"
            },
            "status_change": {
                "new_name": "Solved",
                "old_name": "Open"
            }
        }
    ]
}

const timestamps = data.updates
  .filter(x => x.status_change && x.status_change.new_name === 'Solved')
  .map(x => x.timestamp);

if(timestamps.length >= 1) {
  console.log('updates:', timestamps);
} else {
  console.log('no updates');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well instead of using [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in your conditions, you better use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which is made for this, and also you can use only one `.some()` call to group all of these conditions.

And instead of writing `x.status_change != null` you can just write `x.status_change`, which gives the same result.

```
console.log(
    ticket.updates ?
      ticket.updates.some(x => x.status_change && x.status_change.new_name === 'Solved') ?
        ticket.updates.find(x => x.status_change && x.status_change.new_name === 'Solved').timestamp :
        'new_name is ' + ticket.updates.find(x => x.status_change).status_change.new_name
      : 'No updates');
```

**Demo:**

```js
let ticket = {
  "updates": [{
    "timestamp": "2018-04-26 06:39:12",
    "by": {
      "name": "A1"
    },
    "status_change": {
      "new_name": "Open",
      "old_name": null
    }
  }, {
    "timestamp": "2018-04-27 00:09:44",
    "by": {
      "name": "B1"
    },
    "status_change": null
  }, {
    "timestamp": "2018-04-27 00:10:09",
    "by": {
      "name": "B1"
    },
    "status_change": {
      "new_name": "Solved",
      "old_name": "Open"
    }
  }]
};


console.log(
    ticket.updates ?
      ticket.updates.some(x => x.status_change && x.status_change.new_name === 'Solved') ?
        ticket.updates.find(x => x.status_change && x.status_change.new_name === 'Solved').timestamp :
        'new_name is ' + ticket.updates.find(x => x.status_change).status_change.new_name
      : 'No updates');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Btw, this gives wrong result. Expected result is **2018-04-27 00:10:09**

Comment: @Bishan Sorry my fault, the condition was missing.

Comment: After the update, Now it's giving the correct result. Thanks for pointing out the null check.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will do what you have asked. `solvedData` will contain timestamp of the objects, in which `status_change` is **Solved**. See code below. Feel free for any question.

```js
var myData = {
    "updates": [{
            "timestamp": "2018-04-26 06:39:12",
            "by": {
                "name": "A1"
            },
            "status_change": {
                "new_name": "Open",
                "old_name": null
            }
        }, {
            "timestamp": "2018-04-27 00:09:44",
            "by": {
                "name": "B1"
            },
            "status_change": null
        }, {
            "timestamp": "2018-04-27 00:10:09",
            "by": {
                "name": "B1"
            },
            "status_change": {
                "new_name": "Solved",
                "old_name": "Open"
            }
        }
    ]
};

var solvedData = [];

var i=0;
if(myData.updates){
    for(i=0;i<myData.updates.length; i++){
        if(myData.updates[i].status_change && myData.updates[i].status_change.new_name === "Solved"){
            solvedData.push(myData.updates[i].timestamp);
        }
    }
}

  for(i=0;i<solvedData.length; i++){
    console.log(solvedData[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

- filtering the existing status_change
- filtering new_name === "Solved"
- mapping timestamps

```js
const tickets = {
  "updates": [{
    "timestamp": "2018-04-26 06:39:12",
    "by": {
      "name": "A1"
    },
    "status_change": {
      "new_name": "Open",
      "old_name": null
    }
  }, {
    "timestamp": "2018-04-27 00:09:44",
    "by": {
      "name": "B1"
    },
    "status_change": null
  }, {
    "timestamp": "2018-04-27 00:10:09",
    "by": {
      "name": "B1"
    },
    "status_change": {
      "new_name": "Solved",
      "old_name": "Open"
    }
  }]
};
console.log(tickets.updates
  .filter(x => x.status_change && x.status_change.new_name === "Solved")
  .map(x => x.timestamp));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the most stupid, but IMHO the simplest solution:

```
var ticket = {"updates":[{"timestamp":"2018-04-26 06:39:12","by":{"name":"A1"},"status_change":{"new_name":"Open","old_name":null}},{"timestamp":"2018-04-27 00:09:44","by":{"name":"B1"},"status_change":null},{"timestamp":"2018-04-27 00:10:09","by":{"name":"B1"},"status_change":{"new_name":"Solved","old_name":"Open"}}]};

for (var i in ticket.updates ) {
    var item=ticket.updates[i];
    if (typeof item.status_change === 'object' && item.status_change !== null) {
             if (item.status_change.new_name === 'Solved') {
                    alert('Found timestamp value: ' + item.timestamp);
             }
    }
}
```